# Как встроить фрагмент веб-страницы в приложение?

Tags: android

Нужно встроить фрагмент веб-страницы в приложение. Как это легко сделать?
P.S Немного потыкал нашёл webview, frame, viewpage как сними работать, и подойдут ли они?

Comment: Вам нужен WebView

Comment: Извините за тупой вопрос. Как дать ссылку webview'у.

Comment: Точно не помню, но, вроде, `webView.loadUrl("URL_HERE")`. Проверьте также, что у вас доступ к интернету указан в манифесте.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: android studio - среда разработки, в нее нет никакой надобности встраивать веб-страницы. не путайте инструмент и то, что вы им делаете

Answer (score 0):

На вопрос ответил  [ЮрийСПб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1) он сказал что надо использовать WebView и задать ссылку через `webView.loadUrl("URL_HERE");` + проверить указан ли доступ к интернету в манифесте.